# GWTP Loading Widget based on Role

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gwtp

I have created the application using GWTP and I need to restrict the widget to load based on user roles. Is it possible in GWT/GWTP.

No widget must be loaded to client side, If the user is not authorized.

All the screens are created in UiBinders.

Thanks,
Bennet.

Answer (score 1):

If you use GWT-P I assume you want to block certain presenters to reveal if the user does not have the needed rights. If that's the case checkout [Presenter-Gatekeeper](https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/wiki/Presenter-Gatekeeper).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, With Gatekeepers I can block the content from view. But in my case I want to avoid loading the content to client when the client is not authorized. Is it possible?